# Many to Many relationship creating same multiple records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, many-to-many, has-many-through

I am current working on a project that includes models like (`projects` and `users).` Both of these models has many-to-many association which is done through `has_many_through` approach.

My third model is `UserProject` which is model joining these two (`Project`, `Users`). Ideally when someone create a record in `UserProject` model, like if `user_id` is `1` and `project_id` is `1`, record should be created but whenever someone tries to make the record with the same `user_id` and `project_id,` it should not be created.

This is the basic principle of m*n relationship in dbms. We know rails generates unique id for every model record, so at this time record is creating every single time someone creates. Is there any solution to this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [uniqueness validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) in your model with `:scope` option

```
class UserProject < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :project_id }
end
```

And also is good idea to make DB constraint

```
class UniqueUserAndProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :user_projects do |t|
      t.index %i[user_id project_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be directly creating associations by creating `UserProject` objects.

Instead, assign users to projects with `Project.find(1).users << User.find(1)`

It appears that this will not duplicate assignments. I tried on a couple of associations and the assignments don't duplicate. Does it work for you?

Comment: sadly It does not work for me